# Ispconfig 3: Error: Authentication failed. Error: Critical error Error: Could not connect to server

Tags: ftp, filezilla, ispconfig

I am using ispconfig, and I have created a FTP user with the respective password. But when I try to connect to that server I hm experiencing this error.

```
Error: Authentication failed. 
Error: Critical error 
Error: Could not connect to server
```

I tried all the solutions given [Here](https://ma.juii.net/blog/fix-ispconfig-ftp-logins), but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the error,

I had used FileZilla to login into the server for uploading some file, and the connection was using the `sftp://` protocol.

When I tried to conenct with the `ftp` account the above error was being reported, even after I updated/confirmed the user `password`.

Finally I realized that the protocol was wrong and after removing the `sftp://` protocol prefix, it defaulted to `ftp://` which the server readily accepted.