# Filezilla sftp authentication failed

Tags: ftp, sftp, filezilla

Error:          Authentication failed.

Error:          Critical error: Could not connect to server

I am using credentials provided by domain service 1&1. I am not a backend or networking person, I am frontend developer. Please help.

OS: macos sierra

Answer (score -2):

Check you INTERNET connection first,if it's ok then try this 
If you have any firewall on your computer disable it may be this work for you

Comment: by checking internet connection u mean to ask if my internet is working? or anything else? internet is working, im at workplace

Comment: r u behind the firewall

Comment: "curl ipecho.net/plain;echo" gives me different ip

and mac>settings>networks shows different ip.

When I ping with IP from "curl ipecho.net/plain;echo" then the result is requested time out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333583/ispconfig-3-error-authentication-failed-error-critical-error-error-could-no

Comment: may be this link helps you dear

Comment: port used is 22

Comment: I checked the link and I have considered that already and selected correct connection type which sftp while trying to connect.

Answer (score -3):

tail ping the server; you might have intermittent internet connection

Comment: check your port